# Implementing EQP Simon's (removing trivial solution)

Tags: quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm, simons-algorithm

I have been studying Brassard and Hoyer's paper, *An Exact Quantum Polynomial-Time Algorithm for Simon's Problem* (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9704027).

I have successfully implemented Section 4.1 Shrinking a Subgroup with a 3-qubit system in Qiskit. Now, I'm attempting to implement Section 4.2 Removing 0 from a subgroup and Section 4.3 Composing our new QP-Algorithm.

Specifically, I'm examining the Proof of Theorem 4.

I'm attempting to explicitly define one of the $\chi$ functions and then apply Lemma 8 to better understand what's going on.

Here's my attempt at defining $\chi_0$.

$\chi_0(g) = g_0$

Now apply Lemma 8 to $\chi_0$.

$A = \{ g \in G | g_0 = 1\}$

$B = \{ g \in G | g_0 = 0\}$

Now defining $S_A$. (The first $i$ in the RHS denotes imaginary $i$)

$S_A|i\rangle|\psi_i\rangle = i|i\rangle|\psi_i\rangle$ if $i \in A$

$S_A|i\rangle|\psi_i\rangle = |i\rangle|\psi_i\rangle$ if $i \in B$

Now if I actually write out the matrix for this operator it should look like this.

$$\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & i \\ \end{matrix} $$

$S_{\{0\}}$ is defined as the operator that changes the phase by $i$ if and only if the state is the zero state. Creating this matrix is trivial.

The paper then defines the *Grover Iteration* as $G = AS_{\{0\}}A^{-1}S_A$ where $A$ is some uniform superposition. I am able to obtain $A$.

My questions are first are there any errors in my above analysis? Second what does $A^{-1}$ denote in this context and how could I obtain it? Lastly, how could I implement this in Qiskit? Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!